# Sitecore purge/write log immediately

Tags: sitecore, log4net, sitecore8

Is there a way to purge the log in Sitecore such that logs are written immediately. It's for production debugging.

Also strolling through log files, there are number of log files e.g. log.date.text and log.date.time.txt. Which one is the latest i.e. with our without time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use next module for production server if you have remote access there : 
   https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_Log_Analyzer.aspx

Other option is to use this module: 
   https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_ScriptLogger.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The log with no timestamp in the file name is the first on for that day.

Answer (score 1):

A new log file is created each time the application pool restarts.

If you haven't changed any of the default log4net settings then the initial log file will be in the format log.yyyyMMdd.txt, each subsequent restart will cause a new file to be generated with the following format log.yyyyMMdd.HHmmss.txt.

The latest log file for the day will be the file with the latest timestamp.